# sqlite JOIN query for multiple entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My database has "diary" table and "food" table. In diary table I have following columns: date, food1,food2, ...food10. In food table I have: id, name, allergen1, allergen2, allergen3. So basically you log up to 10 foods a day to diary. Now I'm trying to build a query which would let me find last date that I've eaten food with allergen3. So that's the query I came up with, which you probably know is not working ;-)

```
    Cursor findDateRes = db.rawQuery("SELECT date(" + DIARY_COL_DATE + ") FROM " + DIARY_TABLE
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food1 ON (food1." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F1 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food2 ON (food2." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F2 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food3 ON (food3." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F3 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food4 ON (food4." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F4 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food5 ON (food5." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F5 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food6 ON (food6." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F6 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food7 ON (food7." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F7 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food8 ON (food8." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F8 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food9 ON (food9." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F9 + ")"
            + " INNER JOIN " + FOOD_TABLE + " food10 ON (food10." + FOOD_COL_1 + " = " + DIARY_TABLE + "." + DIARY_COL_F10 +
            ") WHERE 1 NOT IN (food1." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food2." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food3." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food4." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food5." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food6." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food7." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food8." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food9." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ",food10." + FOOD_COL_5 +
            ") ORDER BY date(" + DIARY_COL_DATE + ") ASC LIMIT 1", null);
```

"FOOD_COL_1" stands for id and "FOOD_COL_5" stands fro allergen3.

Thank you for looking. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: read about "normalisation of database". Show database structure

Comment: Without the table schemas and the explanation of their related fields, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Do you actually need such a crazy query? can't it be simplified?

Comment: @ModularSynth I don't, that is why I'm asking for help. I'm new in sqlite.

Comment: @janos DIARY_COL_F1 to F10 are columns in table diary which hold int that corresponds to id of items in food table. Other things I've mentioned are name, which is just name in food table and allergens which are ints and hold value of 0 or 1 to point if food has specific allergen (I probably could have used Boolean for that).

Comment: That's SQL, you are new to. Not SQLite itself. SQL is the language used by most modern RDBMS. Including SQLite.

Comment: @JacekCz are you suggesting that instead of having one date entry in (table) diary holding 10 ids of food (from food table) it would be better to have 10 entries with the same date but single food id? - I can see how much easier and simpler the search query would be.

Comment: @ModularSynth SQL lite is too much tolerant for strange ideas (IMHO), for example effectively has no column type, bad for teaching. Agree, many other SQL databases exists

Comment: @aya9 yes, this kind of decomposition. Must discus for example "create" statements, not "select"

Comment: @JacekCz I guess you meant `SQLite has no *boolean* type`. But you can manage that easily by using an integer column type and handle it in your app.

Comment: @ModularSynth AFAIK numeric are not true numeric columns, but string incarnation. Can write all traditional types in "create table", but result is "universal character column"

Comment: @JacekCz INTEGER and REAL are numeric types. https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I have remeber (mostly ;) ) good, but You are right in details  . read part 3. Type Affinity. EDIT From my point of view, affinity is bad at learning stage

Comment: Well, affinity is not too bad, after all. You don't have to write TEXT necessarily, you can write STRING and it is the same. Not a big deal - probably it helps those ones who come from other RDBMS and are used to write VARCHAR... ;)