# Designing date orientated database sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new in sqlite. I've built database but based on query I was trying to solve for it (which was over-complicated), I was suggested to look into normalising database, which I did, but can't seem to find examples on database that would be orientated around dates like a diary, with lots of daily entries. I'm working on app that would help log in everyday what I've eaten, what exercise did I do, what activities I've done, what was my well-being, how many hours I've slept. I will be able to go back to any day in the past and see what I was up to, so it will have to look up all entries for that particular date.

So I understand I need separate tables for food type, exercise type, activities types, event types and I need main table "diary" which will log each time date and id referencing another table. So I'm wondering if in that diary table I can have date column, id column and lets say type column (which will differentiate which table does id column references) or should I rather have date column and column for each of the other tables ids, even though I will be logging only one type at the time?

Also, would indexing the date column be a good idea?

Or maybe there is a better way to design that database? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: No thing special, you just need to **Post** data and **Get** data. 

`would indexing the date column be a good idea?` this belong to you.

`there is a better way to design that database?` you design it as needed.

Comment: @Ibrahim I have designed as needed, the app works, logs and updates data, though making some join query for some data lookup proved to be quite awkward and troublesome for future updates. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651712/sqlite-join-query-for-multiple-entries)

Comment: Well, i will say something that dosen't related to the question, but analysis the project as needed from the beginning would be a good idea, You need to see advanced sql code from proffessional programmers to avoid those mistakes.

Comment: @Ibrahim, like I wrote I had a look at different examples, but most of them are for employes or retail, customers or some sort of stock databases, not date orientated diary database. I've made database for website project using mysql and did not have problems with it for over 2 years. Just wanted some tip or pointing in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> So I understand I need separate tables for food type, exercise type,
> activities types, event types

If normalising then perhaps consider a single table for all types with a column to indicate the type.

> So I'm wondering if in that diary table I can have date column, id
> column and lets say type column (which will differentiate which table
> does id column references) or should I rather have date column and
> column for each of the other tables ids, even though I will be logging
> only one type at the time?

If you are logging and assuming human input (as opposed to automated) then it is highly likely that a timestamp would be sufficient to uniquely identify a row.
As such there would be little need for an id column(*in theory*).

Saying that SQLite, unless you specify `WITHOUT ROWID` (which you might consider,  this may be of use in deciding:-[Clustered Indexes and the WITHOUT ROWID Optimization](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) ), automatically creates a unique row identifier column i.e **ROWID**.

If you code a column as `columnname INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `columnname INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` then `columnname` becomes an alias for `ROWID`, in which case the unique value will be provided, if you do not provide a value when inserting.

However, if you were to specify `timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and provide the current date/time as a value for the column when inserting, the current date/time would be stored and would also be indexed (it would have to be unique (current date/time would very likely be)).

So I'd suggest that a log entry need only be something like `CREATE TABLE log (timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, eventref INTEGER);`, where `eventref` is a reference to the event type.

As **_id** is required at times e.g. for a CursorAdapter then you could specify the columns to be extracted as `*, timestemp as _id` (*3 columns timestamp, eventref and _id (timestamp and _id would be identical)*)or `timstemp as _id, *` (*3 columns but _id, timestamp and eventref*) or `timestamp as _id, eventref` (*2 columns _id and eventref*).

So using this model as the basis would minimise columns and be indexed automatically.

### An example

#### You may have the events table as :-

[image]

#### Along with log table as :-

[image]

#### A query such as `SELECT * FROM log JOIN events WHERE eventref = _id` would give:-

[image]

*Note! made up timestamps for illustration purposes*

Comment: first of all thank you very much for taking time to help me. I thought of using timestamp to create unique entries, but user needs to be able to enter data at any time, even days and months after that have happened. Also diary has 4 different times a day (morning, noon, afternoon and evening), there is a lot of data going in everyday. There is also option to add notes for every type of data (not item, so lets say comment about eating) per date and time of day. There is also actions that will let you copy some of the patterns from previous days.

Comment: Before diary table had one entry for each date and time of day but that table had nearly 100 of columns (to fit potential ids and values of each item plus notes) , but I guess that wasn't a good idea, so I'm trying to make it better. But it means that now table will have up to 100 of entries for each date and time of day, but I understand that will work for the best.